# Events in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, events, scope

Is there some system of global events in ReactJS?
Something like $rootScope.$broadcast and scope.$on in AngularJS.
Is there something like that in ReactJS, and if it is, where can I find some information about it?

Comment: no, that's why there are libraries like redux and mobx as ReactJS is just the view layer. You could also use a tiny events library for triggering those you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks alot. Well, could you please tell me, where can I find info about tiny events library?

Comment: Do you mean something like https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html ?

Comment: @alxaux there are many you can search for "javascript event emitter" e.g. https://github.com/facebook/emitter but bare in mind they are suitable for stateless events, not storing app state and making your app re-render when it e.g. receives data from an API (that's what redux and mobx etc are for)

Comment: Redux isn't 1:1 match but it's very close. It's more like applying changes to $rootScope and `$watch`ing changes on inherited $scope. It can be expressed natively in React with context API + 16.7 useReducer hook.